# How to static_assert that a given function call expression would compile or not?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates, c++17

Is there a way to check if a function call expression would compile at compile and static_assert on it?  Or should I just invoke the compiler thru `system()` and check for exit code?

```
#include <type_traits>

template < typename... Args >
void f(Args && ... args, bool);

template < typename... Args >
void g(Args && ... args);

int main()
{
    g(1, 2.0, "hello", false);  //  compiles
    f(1, 2.0, "hello", false);  //  doesn't compile
    //  How do I do this?
    //  static_assert(!does_this_compile(f(1, 2.0, "hello", false)), "As expected");
}
```

Comment: What for? Compiler always static_asserts all your code for compilability. I suppose, your guess about `system()` is a right way to go.

Comment: This kind of thing is normally done by the build system; almost all build systems have some `try_compile` which sets a variable depending on the success of compilation.

Comment: @zrb - semplified my answer: no need of `bar` struct, more flexibility in use of parameters. But I don't know to avoid the use of `FooF` and `FooG` structs (that is: I don't know how to check `f()` and `g()` directly)

Comment: Would invoking an instance of clang that you've linked into your program suffice?  The boilerplate would be bad, but it''s probably viable for a form of unit test

Answer (score 4):

First wrap the call result into a type:

```
template<class...Args>
using f_r=decltype(f(std::declval<Args>()...));
```

Now `f_r<int>` is the type of calling `f` with an `int` rvalue.

Next write this:

```
namespace details{
  template<template<class...>class Z, class, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z,std::void_t<Z<Ts...>>,Ts...>:std::true_type{};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
struct can_apply:details::can_apply<Z,void,Ts...>;
```

Now use it:

```
template<class...Args>
using can_f = can_apply<f_r, Args...>;
```

Which gives us:

```
static_assert(!can_f<int, double, decltype("hello"), bool>{}, "As expected");
```

This only checks for *early* errors, basically the ones that get caught before the body is parsed. (SFINAE "errors")  Later errors are permitted to be fatal and uncheckable.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it's possible in a simpler way, but...

If you can insert your functions in a struct (`fooF` for `f()` and `fooG` for `g()`, in the following example) as `constexpr` (and `const`) members with the same name (`Func()`), if you can they return a type different from `void` (or the `constexpr` part isn't working (at least with my clang++)), then you can create a couple of `constexpr` `checkCompile()` functions; then you can use `checkCompile()` in a `static_assert`

The following example work with both g++ 4.9.2 and clang++ 3.5

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct fooF
 {
   template < typename... Args >
      constexpr int func (Args && ... args, bool) const
       { return 0; }
 };

struct fooG
 {
   template < typename... Args >
      constexpr int func (Args && ... args) const
       { return 0; }
 };

template <typename C, typename ... Args>
   static constexpr auto checkCompile (C const & c, Args ... args)
   -> decltype( c.func(args...), int() )
    { return 1; }

template <typename ...>
   static constexpr auto checkCompile (...) -> int
    { return 0; }

int main()
 {
   std::cout << checkCompile(fooF(), 1, 2.0, "hello", false) << '\n';
   std::cout << checkCompile(fooG(), 1, 2.0, "hello", false) << '\n';

   static_assert(0 == checkCompile(fooF(), 1, 2.0, "hello", false), "!");
   static_assert(1 == checkCompile(fooG(), 1, 2.0, "hello", false), "!");

   return 0;
 }
```

p.s.: should work with C++11 too.

p.s.2: sorry for my bad English.